# Before filter on condition

Tags: filter, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app where all routes require a user login by default. Something like this:

```
before do 
  env['warden'].authenticate!
end

get :index do
  render :index
end
```

Now I would like to use a custom Sinatra condition to make exceptions, but I cannot find a way to read if the condition is true/false/nil

```
def self.public(enable)
  condition {
    if enable 
      puts 'yes'
    else
      puts 'no'
    end
  }
end

before do 
  # unless public?
  env['warden'].authenticate!
end

get :index do
  render :index
end

get :foo, :public => true do
  render :index
end
```

Since the authentication check must be done even if the condition is not defined, I guess I still must use a `before` filter, but I am not sure how to access my custom condition.

Comment: The public method is not available in before context as it's defined as class method. Have you checked when the method was defined as instance method(without self)?

Comment: If I define the method as instance (without self), then I will not be able to use it as a rule condition, and I would like to preserve that way of writing public urls in the DSL. I was thinking about about **before** reading the conditions of the request object, or define **public => false** as a default condition for any rule. In any case, I just wanted an easy way to specify a few exceptions to a default rule.

Comment: what I did notice, was that conditions seems to be parsed **after** the filter, and that was the point when I ran out of ideas.

Comment: so far I solved this problem with a conditional skipping the authentication only if the login url is detected, but that is not very future proof.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using Sinatra's [helpers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers) and some digging into Sinatra's [internals](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L993). I think this should work for you:

```
helpers do
  def skip_authentication?
    possible_routes = self.class.routes[request.request_method]

    possible_routes.any? do |pattern, _, conditions, _|
      pattern.match(request.path_info) &&
        conditions.any? {|c| c.name == :authentication }
    end
  end
end

before do
  skip_authentication? || env['warden'].authenticate!
end

set(:authentication) do |enabled|
  condition(:authentication) { true } unless enabled
end

get :index do
  render :index
end

get :foo, authentication: false do
  render :index
end
```