# Exclude some paths from global authentication in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra

I have an API in Sinatra, using a middleware doing a global restrict authentication with token.
This middleware inserts the authentication check in a before statement, in order to protect everything globally without the need to add a check in each route definition.

```
before do
  denied unless
    authorized? or
    env['PATH_INFO'] == '/auth/login' or
    env['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS' # For AngularJS headers checks
end
```

But now I have some routes I need to exclude from this global restrictions (only 2 or 3 on tens) and don't know how to do that.

I first think about Sinatra conditions : http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Conditions but since it's in a before statements, I'm unable to take action to avoid that before.

I then found this solution : [Before filter on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380342/before-filter-on-condition)

But it's not really a clean way to do it and it can't work for me with middlewares and a modular Sinatra app.

So after having searching a lot, I need some help and advices.

How to do that, maybe with helpers, conditions, and some modifications in my middleware ?

Comment: Authentication and authorization are two different things, but the way this is written they appear to be conflated. Just saying.

Comment: @iain It isn't. All the API was requiring authentication, so either you're already authorized or you need to authenticate, that's the purpose of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not put the list of routes that need no authorisation into an array and check it?

```
configure do
  set :no_auth_neededs, ['/auth/login', "/a", "/b", "/c"]
end

before do
  denied unless
    authorized? or
    settings.no_auth_neededs.include?(env['PATH_INFO']) or
    env['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS' # For AngularJS headers checks
end
```

I haven't tested this.

---

Update:

There are two other ways I can think of doing this that my laziness doesn't whine about, if I put in 10 seconds of thinking time… but I'm happy to trust intuition :)

#### Extending the DSL

Write an `authorised_route` handler:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module AuthorisedRoute
    def authorised_route(verb,path,&block)
      before path do
        denied unless
          authorized? or
          request.request_method == 'OPTIONS' # For AngularJS headers checks
      end
      send verb.to_sym, path, &block
    end
  end

  register AuthorisedRoute
end

class API < Sinatra::Base
  register AuthorisedRoute

  authorised_route "get", "/blah" do
    # blah
  end

  get "/free-route" do
    # blah
  end
end
```

You could remove that `before` block and just put the logic in the route, YMMV. There's lots of ways to use this kind of thing. Note the replacement of `env` with `request` (see [Accessing the Request Object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object))

[See the docs for more on DSL extensions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending-the-dsl-class-context-with-sinatraregister)

#### Use a class

Separate out the two types of route, that's what classes are for, groups of things that share attributes and/or behaviour:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class AuthedAPI < Sinatra::Base

  before do
    denied unless
      authorized? or
      request.request_method == 'OPTIONS' # For AngularJS headers checks
  end

  # you should probably add the `denied` and `authorized?` helpers too

  # list of routes follow…
end

# define route that don't need auth in here
class OpenAPI < Sinatra::Base
  get "/auth/login" do
    # stuff…
  end
end

class API < Sinatra::Base
  use OpenAPI  # put OpenAPI first or a `denied` will happen.
  use AuthedAPI
end
```

and then map the `API` to `"/"` (or whatever the API's root path is) in the rackup file. Only the routes in AuthedAPI will be subject to the `before` block.

Comment: That's a nice idea, and if I don't find anything else i will surely go this way for now. But i prefer to do it when defining a route, if any suitable manner to do it, since I need to filter the route AND the specific method to access it.

Comment: @Sylver I've updated the answer with a couple of alternatives that may interest you.

Comment: I'll go for the DSL extension I think, thanks for all your clever thoughts on that !