# How do I ignore the authenticity token for specific actions in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

When I have a specific action that I don't want to check the authenticity token on, how do I tell Sinatra to skip checking it?

in Rails we have `skip_before_action :authenticate_request`

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604380/exclude-some-paths-from-global-authentication-in-sinatra

Comment: @PavelOganesyan thank you very much, i did not saw that question